# Unable to read a hive table from zepplin notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-zeppelin

I am new to spark and I am querying the below command and it is failing with the error:-

```
val cop_raw = sqlContext.sql("select * from cop.p_id")
cop_raw.show(5)

java.io.IOException: 
shadehive.org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.io.IOException: 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Failed to compile query: 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 1:400 
Failed to recognize predicate 'date'. 
Failed rule: 'identifier' in table or column identifier
```

Can somebody suggest how to fix it?

I could see that by setting the below can fix the issue but I am not sure how to run this command on zeppelin when hive interpreter is not set.

```
SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false
```

Comment: Which version of Spark?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
sqlContext.sql("SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false;")
```

For me this works in Spark2:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.sql("SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false;")
```